# How to manage multiple timers in one viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I'm working on Timers app and cannot understand how I can make work multiple timers for each cell.

I start and pause timers at didSelectRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
    let item = timers.items[indexPath.row]
    item.toggle()
    print(item)
    startPauseTimer(for: cell, with: item)
}
```

And this is my code for startPauseTimer:

```
   var timer = Timer()

    func startPauseTimer(for cell: TimerTableViewCell, with item: Timers) {
       if !item.isStarted {
           timer.invalidate()
           } else {    
           timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {timer in
                item.seconds -= 1
                cell.timerTime.text = self.formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(item.seconds))

               if item.seconds < 1 {
                   self.timer.invalidate()
                   cell.timerTime.text = self.formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(item.seconds))
                   item.isStarted = false
               }
        }
       }
    }
```

And my data model:

```
class Timers: NSObject, Codable {
  var name = ""
  var id = ""
  var seconds = 0
  var editSeconds = 0
  var isStarted = false

  func toggle() {
        isStarted = !isStarted
    }
```

Any my Cell code:

```
class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var timerTime: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var startPauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var resetButton: UIButton!    

    }
```

How I can manage multiple timers at once? When I use didSelectRowAt only the same Timer() instance is firing, so multiple timers is mixing. How I can divide multiple timers and make them work?

Comment: Can you add your TimerTableViewCell definition?

Comment: I added, but it has only outlets.

Comment: @alexsmith - please don't post multiple versions of the same question. Edit this one, and try to do a better job of explaining what you are trying to do, rather than posting partial code that "isn't working*. What do you mean by a *"Timers app"*? What are you trying to accomplish? Your basic approach my be wrong, so the multiple comments / answers you get on multiple posts of this question may have nothing to do with solving the basic approach to begin with.

Comment: @alexsmith - take a look at this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113835-ios-timer-tutorial ... with very minor changes, it looks like it could do just what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete example, based on [iOS Timer Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113835-ios-timer-tutorial) by [Fabrizio Brancati](https://www.raywenderlich.com/u/fbrancati) at RayWenderlich.com

Everything is done via code (no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections needed), so just create a new `UITableViewController` and assign its custom class to `ExampleTableViewController`:

---

**ExampleTableViewController.swift**

```
//
//  ExampleTableViewController.swift
//  MultipleTimers
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 5/12/20.
//

import UIKit

class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellID: String = "TaskCell"

    var taskList: [Task] = []
    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // -1 means use default 2-hours
        let sampleData: [(String, Double)] = [
            ("First (2 hours)", -1),
            ("Second (2 hours)", -1),
            ("Third (10 seconds)", 10),
            ("Fourth (30 seconds)", 30),
            ("Fifth (1 hour 10 minutes)", 60 * 70),
            ("Sixth (2 hours)", -1),
            ("Seventh (45 minutes)", 60 * 45),
            ("Eighth (2 hours)", -1),
            ("Ninth (1 hour 10 minutes)", 60 * 70),
            ("Tenth (2 hours)", -1),
            ("Eleventh (45 minutes)", 60 * 45),
            ("Thirteenth (2 hours)", -1),
            ("Fourteenth (2 minutes)", 60 * 2),
            ("Fifthteenth (11 minutes)", 60 * 11),
            ("Sixteenth (2 hours)", -1),
        ]

        sampleData.forEach { (s, t) in
            let task = Task(name: s, targetTime: t)
            self.taskList.append(task)
        }

        tableView.register(TaskCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)

        createTimer()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        cell.task = taskList[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}

// MARK: - Timer
extension ExampleTableViewController {
    func createTimer() {
        if timer == nil {
            let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                              target: self,
                              selector: #selector(updateTimer),
                              userInfo: nil,
                              repeats: true)
            RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
            timer.tolerance = 0.1

            self.timer = timer
        }
    }

    func cancelTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        guard let visibleRowsIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
            return
        }

        for indexPath in visibleRowsIndexPaths {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TaskCell {
                cell.updateTime()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**TaskCell.swift**

```
//
//  TaskCell.swift
//  MultipleTimers
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 5/12/20.
//

import UIKit

class TaskCell: UITableViewCell {

    let taskNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    let timerLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .medium)
        return v
    }()

    let actionButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("Start", for: [])
        v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        v.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .disabled)
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.75, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()

    let resetButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("Reset", for: [])
        v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        v.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .disabled)
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let buttonStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 16
        return v
    }()

    var task: Task? {
        didSet {
            taskNameLabel.text = task?.name
            timerLabel.text = "0"
            setState()
            updateTime()
        }
    }

    func setState() -> Void {

        switch task?.state {
        case .running:
            actionButton.setTitle("Pause", for: [])
            actionButton.isEnabled = true
        case .paused:
            if task?.elapsedTime == 0 {
                actionButton.setTitle("Start", for: [])
                actionButton.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                actionButton.setTitle("Resume", for: [])
                actionButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        default: // .completed
            actionButton.setTitle("", for: [])
            actionButton.isEnabled = false
        }

    }

    func updateTime() {
        guard let task = task else {
            return
        }

        var t: Double = 0
        if task.state == .paused {
            t = task.targetTime - task.elapsedTime
        } else {
            t = task.targetTime - (Date().timeIntervalSince(task.creationDate) + task.elapsedTime)
        }

        let tm = Int(max(t, 0))

        let hours = tm / 3600
        let minutes = tm / 60 % 60
        let seconds = tm % 60

        let s = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
        timerLabel.text = s
        timerLabel.textColor = tm > 0 ? .black : .red
        if tm == 0 {
            task.state = .completed
            setState()
        }
    }

    @objc
    func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        guard let s = sender.currentTitle, let task = task else { return }
        switch s {

        case "Start", "Resume":
            task.state = .running
            task.creationDate = Date()

        case "Pause":
            task.state = .paused
            task.elapsedTime += Date().timeIntervalSince(task.creationDate)

        case "Reset":
            task.state = .paused
            task.elapsedTime = 0

        default:
            break
        }
        setState()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        [buttonStack, resetButton, actionButton, timerLabel, taskNameLabel].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(actionButton)
        buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(resetButton)

        contentView.addSubview(buttonStack)
        contentView.addSubview(taskNameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(timerLabel)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            buttonStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            buttonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            buttonStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280.0),

            taskNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            taskNameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            taskNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonStack.widthAnchor),

            timerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: taskNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            timerLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            timerLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonStack.widthAnchor),

            timerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

}
```

---

**Task.swift**

```
//
//  Task.swift
//  MultipleTimers
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 5/12/20.
//

import Foundation

enum TimerState {
    case paused, running, completed
}

class Task {
    let name: String
    var creationDate = Date()
    var elapsedTime: Double = 0
    var state: TimerState = .paused
    var targetTime: Double = 60 * 60 * 2 // default 2 hours

    init(name: String, targetTime: Double) {
        self.name = name
        if targetTime != -1 {
            self.targetTime = targetTime
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here's how it looks while running:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's only one instance of Timer kept, so it can be replaced with other timer when you don't want it.

And it's better to pass row instead of cell object to `startPauseTimer` since cells are normally reused. And then you can address required cell and change its text via `func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`.

Let's create `TimerModel` class:

```
class TimerModel {
    let timer: Timers
    var actualTimer: Timer?

    init(_ timer: Timers) {
        self.timer = timer
        self.actualTimer = nil
    }
}
```

Then suppose you have `timers = [TimerModel(Timers()), TimerModel(Timers())]`

Selecting a row:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
    let item = timers[indexPath.row]
    item.timer.toggle()
    print(item)
    startPauseTimer(for: indexPath.row)
}
```

startPause:

```
func startPauseTimer(for row: Int) {
    let item = self.timers[row].timer
    if !item.isStarted {
        self.timers[row].actualTimer?.invalidate()
    } else {
        self.timers[row].actualTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {[weak self] timer in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let cell =  self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) {
                item.seconds -= 1
                cell.textLabel?.text = "\(TimeInterval(item.seconds))"

                if item.seconds < 1 {
                    self.timers[row].actualTimer?.invalidate()
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(TimeInterval(item.seconds))"
                    item.isStarted = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to remove a row (to be called when row is removed by user or programmatically):

```
func onRemove(at row: Int) {
    timers[row].actualTimer?.invalidate()
    timers[row].actualTimer = nil
    timers.remove(at: row)
}
```

Please see apple docs for editing UITableView:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview

- **Putting the Table into Edit Mode** if you want to edit by interaction with cells
- **Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections** if you want to edit rows programmatically.

Comment: I cannot move var timer to Timers class, because it won't be conform to Codable protocol.

Comment: Even having an array of timers won't help since it would be tedious to keep track of the modification of items list. i.e when an item added / removed, the corresponding timer should also be added / removed.

Comment: It will work. And it can be wrapped in some other class for convenience.

Comment: Can you provide sample code? How I can add and remove timers in array? And how it can be wrapped in some other class?

Comment: @alexsmith, ok, see the latest edit. This should give illustrate the approach.

Comment: Thank for your code, but I think It will be much simple to put the code of executing timers in TimerTableViewCell.

Comment: @alexsmith, it might seem easier, but note that cells are usually reused.
If you use 
`func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` in your `cellFoRow` method, then if you say scroll your table view then timer in cell might be replaced with new one when cell is reused.

Comment: And can be this problem solved with reused cells if I put my code for executing timers in TimerTableViewCell? Or it's better to use your method?

Comment: It sure can, but I don't see it being easy. The general idea of easy solution is to keep timers outside cells since they logically more attached to data model than to view.
And this can be done with solution above, for example.

Comment: When I try to use your code, I get Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range. What's the better place to append new timers in timers array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213696/discussion-between-alexsmith-and-daniel-ovchinnikov).