# Timer being reused in UItableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, prepareforreuse

I am working on my UITableviewcell where I have a UIView for user to "tap" and start timer. I am creating my UItableview cell components completely programmatically and adding timer components within UITableviewcell class instead of the parent view controller.

The problem I am having is that my timer is supposed to be distinct for each UITableviewcell. User should be able to start timer in one cell and scroll through other cells to start/stop another. However, when I "tap" on my first cell, the timer gets started not only on the first one, but I can also see that it is starting on the 3rd cell.

I tried to rectify this issue by using PrepareForReuse and invalidate timer, but it also result in the 1st cell's timer to be invalidated.

I tried to research on this issue, but have found no exact match. Could anyone kindly advise how I can resolve this issue?

```
class ActiveExerciseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    static let tableviewidentifier = "activeExerciseTableViewCell"
    
    var tableviewContentViewTabBarHeight = CGFloat()
    
    var exerciseCellKeyboardHeight = CGFloat()
    
    var restTimer = Timer()
    var restTimeRemaining: Int = 180
    var isRestTimerRunning: Bool = false

    let activeExerciseTimerUIView: UIView = {
        let activeExerciseTimerUIView = UIView()
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        return activeExerciseTimerUIView
    }()
    
    let timerLabel: UILabel = {
        let timerLabel = UILabel()
        timerLabel.text = "180"
        timerLabel.textColor = .black
        timerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return timerLabel
    }()


    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        if self.isRestTimerRunning == false {
            restTimer.invalidate()
            restTimeRemaining = 180
            timerLabel.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(restTimeRemaining))
        }

    }


func setUpActiveExerciseUIViewLayout(){
        
        timerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        timerLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        timerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: (contentView.frame.height-tableviewContentViewTabBarHeight)*0.55).isActive = true
        timerLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentView.frame.width * 0.7).isActive = true
        timerLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        timerLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 64)
        
        
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: (contentView.frame.height-tableviewContentViewTabBarHeight)*0.25).isActive = true
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 225).isActive = true
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 225).isActive = true

        let timerStartGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playTapped))
        timerStartGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.addGestureRecognizer(timerStartGesture)
        activeExerciseTimerUIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    }


 @objc func playTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if isRestTimerRunning == false {
            restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(step), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.isRestTimerRunning = true
        }
      
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func pauseTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        restTimer.invalidate()
    }
    

    @IBAction func resetTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        restTimer.invalidate()
        restTimeRemaining = 180
        timerLabel.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(restTimeRemaining))
    }
    
    
    @objc func step() {
        if restTimeRemaining > 0 {
            restTimeRemaining -= 1
        } else {
            restTimer.invalidate()
            restTimeRemaining = 180
        }
        timerLabel.text = prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval(restTimeRemaining))
    }
    
    public func prodTimeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let Minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let Seconds = Int(time) % 60

        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", Minutes, Seconds)
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you shouldn't be storing *any* `Timer` logic inside your cells -- those should be for UI only. Instead, create a separate data model that stores your timers and the indexes and write the table UI to reflect the states of the timers.

Comment: One other thing is that when cell is reuse the timer may be invalidated. This will happen when you scroll. The tsp on the timer button should be handle in the table view controller with one timer for each cell . You could an array or a dictionary of timer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will create a separate data model and work on it and I also found some sample solutions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750038/how-to-manage-multiple-timers-in-one-viewcontroller I will update my code and post my solution if I manage to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam posting my own answer, issue had been resolved the issue by

1. Creating a separate view model that stores timer.
2. Initializing UITableView cell by using unique "reuseID" from tableview delegate.

```
SetViewModel

class SetViewModel {
    
    init(set: SetInformation) {
        self.set = set
        self.secondsRemaining = set.restTime ?? 0
        self.elapsedSeconds = 0
        self.isTimerRunning = false
        self.currentBackgroundDate = nil
        self.buttonPressCount = 0

    }
    
    var set: SetInformation
    var secondsRemaining: Int
    var elapsedSeconds: Int
    var isTimerRunning: Bool
    var currentBackgroundDate: Date?
    var buttonPressCount: Int
    
    weak var delegate: SetViewModelDelegate?
    
    // MARK: - Timer
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    func startTimer() {
        //stopTimer()
        isTimerRunning = true
        timer = .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            guard let self = self else {
                // If the model was discarded during the runtime of the timer
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            
            if self.secondsRemaining > 0 && self.elapsedSeconds < (self.secondsRemaining + self.elapsedSeconds) {
                self.secondsRemaining -= 1
                self.elapsedSeconds += 1
            } else {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
            
            self.delegate?.setTimerUpdated(model: self)
            
        })
    }
    
    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        isTimerRunning = false
        self.delegate?.setTimerUpdated(model: self)
    }
```

UItableView Delegate

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let reuseID = String(indexPath.row) + ActiveExerciseTableViewCell.tableviewidentifier
        
        activeExerciseTableView.register(ActiveExerciseTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        
        let cell = activeExerciseTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath) as! ActiveExerciseTableViewCell
        
        //configure set information for the tableview cell based on setviewmodel
        cell.configure(setViewModel: setViewModels[indexPath.row], currentHeartRate: userCurrentHeartRate ?? 00)
        
        cell.setDescriptionLabel.text = "Set \(String(indexPath.row + 1)) of \(activeExerciseList[activeDisplayedExericseRow].setInformation!.count)"
        
        cell.tableviewContentViewTabBarHeight = contentViewTabBarHeight
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```